# Downloading iOS Simulator does not proceed ahead authorization was denied

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, xcode8

I am trying to download iOS 9.3 Simulator from Xcode 8.1 But some times downloading fails due to time out but after using 4G Network I got this error. I have iPhone 4S with iOS 9.3.5 version, so I want to test my app on my iPhone. As Xcode 8+ does not support iPhone 4S because it has lower deployment target so I have changed my Xcode's deployment target to iOS 9.3 from 10.1. That's why I am trying to download and install the iOS Simulator. Kindly share your ideas in this regard.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When simulator about to end installation process it requires authentication but I forgot to look over screen and this pop was appeared.